# How to add images to a push notification?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, mobile

Is there any chance to add images to a push notification?

That would be a brand logo, user picture etc.

Comment: You may wish to state what technology you are using for push notifications. You might also have better luck splitting this up into separate questions per OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except from Emoji iOS does not support images in push notification.